# Gravitational radiation in M theory and super string theory

Tags: string-theory, quantum-gravity, gravitational-waves, greens-functions

Hey I'm trying to build a toy model of gravitational radiation for fun from M theory.

I need some general help with selecting thru the ideas I have.

My first "model" is to make a M2 brane with gravitational charge on each brane. The string tension would then be my gravitational potential. Using dualities and the symmetry of this ideal situation. I was thinking of using a compactification model. That is represent them as a closed string at time T that shrinks thus the total energy radiated would be proportional to ln|r1-r2|. In a way I see this as a time evolution Operator method if that makes sense.

Another way was directly from the equations of motion and the momentum modeling it as acceleration and energy flux. Similar to how we model EM radiation.

But in GR we simply vary the action according to a small perturbation.Putting the string the Einstein frame and having a massless condition should gives us the massless pertubations of the field which are essentially all produced by spin 2 particle.

Or maybe some kind of S matrix method.I'm a bit confused as to which one to use. I realize it's probably a dumb question but I'm having trouble finding the right literature.

I do recall a green function derived by witten for the change of radii of a string.

I do realize this is probably a very naive way of looking at the problem but I'm trying to get a better feel of how to manipulate stuff in the theory.

Comment: This question has been flagged as low-quality and voted for deletion.

Comment: Most of what you write is complete nonsense. A sample of errors you made:1) It's not clear if you are talking about $M$-theory or string theory. 2) The string tension cannot be used as a "grvitational potential" 3) you "compactification model" is vague and usless. Your last four paragraphs are terribly wrong.

Comment: I also flagged this question for deletion because of its low quality.

Answer (score 2):

I see two simple ways to proceed. One is to be concerned with the emission of small numbers of gravitons. The other is to describe emission of gravitational waves, which involve enormous numbers of gravitons.

The string-theoretic approach to the emission of a few gravitons is similar to the approach one would use in quantum field theory. In QFT, you would sum over Feynman diagrams; in string theory, you use the topological sum over string histories, which is a path integral over string worldsheet histories, carried out using a 2d conformal field theory specific to the background geometry. You could search on keywords "graviton emission" "string theory".

For a gravitational wave, the simplest approach is to neglect both quantum mechanics and the string length, and to just work directly in a classical field theory, presumably some kind of supergravity. Then you can describe massive objects e.g. branes orbiting each other, just as you would in general relativity (but with some extra fields). You could try searching on "gravitational wave" "supergravity" (and to actually connect it to strings, specialize to supergravities that arise as limits of string theory, like type I/II supergravity, heterotic supergravity, NS-NS supergravity).

Quantum field theory describes how to build up classical field states from particles. I suppose that in string theory, the analogous transition is most commonly discussed in the context of "fluxes".